# How to interpolate environment variables within netlify.toml config

Tags: netlify

I want to proxy to a different api depending on the environment - I've tried a few variations on the following theme without any luck. What's the correct way of doing this, if its even possible?

```
[build.environment]
  API_URI="https://dev-api.foo.com/:splat"

[context.production.environment]
  API_URI="https://prod-api.foo.com/:splat"

[[redirects]]
  from = "/api/*"
  to = "$API_URI"
  status = 200
  force = true
```

This does not work.

Although the above config works when I hardcode a URI into the `to` field, it just fails when I try to interpolate an env var.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not supported, but Netlify suggest a work-around in their documentation (https://www.netlify.com/docs/netlify-toml-reference):

> Using Environment Variables directly as values ($VARIABLENAME) in your
>   netlify.toml file is not supported. However, the following workflow
>   can be used to substitute values based on environment variables in the
>   file, assuming you are only trying to change headers or redirects. The
>   rest of the file is read BEFORE your build - but those sections are
>   read AFTER the build process.
>
> 1. Add a placeholder like
>      API_KEY_PLACEHOLDER somewhere in the netlify.toml redirects or headers
>      sections.
> 2. Create an Build Environment Variable, for example API_KEY,
>      with the desired value. You can do this in the toml file or in our UI
>      in the Build and Deploy Settings section of your configuration. You
>      might use the latter to keep sensitive values out of your repository.
> 3. Add a command like this one to your build command: sed -i
>      s/API_KEY_PLACEHOLDER/$API_KEY/g netlify.toml && normal build command.

Comment: What's the syntax for this? I can't seem to get it to work right now. I've tried `sed -i s/PLACEHOLDER/$VARIABLE/g netlify.toml` and `sed -i s/PLACEHOLDER/${VARIABLE}/g netlify.toml` (currently recommended by the docs) but neither works.

Comment: In your netlify.toml:
```[context.deploy-preview.environment]
  SERVER_DOMAIN="blablabla.com"

[build]
publish = "build"
command = "sed -i s/SERVER_DOMAIN_PLACEHOLDER/$SERVER_DOMAIN/g netlify.toml && npm run build"
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question - it's not supported, you have to manually interpolate env vars yourself as part of the build on Netlify.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's possible. Here is the detailed docs: https://www.netlify.com/docs/continuous-deployment/#deploy-contexts

In my case, I need to set a `REACT_APP_API_URL` separate for production and all other branches. Here is what I use:

```
[context.production.environment]
  REACT_APP_API_URL = "https://api.test.im"

[context.deploy-preview.environment]
  REACT_APP_API_URL = "https://api-staging.test.im"

[context.branch-deploy.environment]
  REACT_APP_API_URL = "https://api-staging.test.im"
```

Comment: Yes, but this question is about taking that env var value and using it elsewhere in the config, like a redirects rule.